# Show that $[\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n\binom{n}{k}]^2=\sum\limits_{r = 0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not sure how to show that $[\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n\binom{n}{k}]^2=\sum\limits_{r = 0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r}$. 
I've heard of $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}$ but I still get nowhere. I have no idea where $r$ came from or why it's $2n$ above the sum.

Comment: From all the answers below, I understand it now. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a basis propertie of Pascal's triangle the LHS can be written as

$$\left[\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\right]^2=[2^n]^2=2^{2n}=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r}$$

The $r$ is just used as a new index to avoid confusions by naming two **different** variables $k$ for example.

Answer (score 4):

Use $$\sum_{f=0}^g{g\choose f}=2^g$$ substituting appropriate values for $f,g$ on both sides of what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{r}x^r = (x+1)^n\Rightarrow (x+1)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r}x^r
$$

with $x = 1$

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a combinatorial proof: given $n$ distinct dogs and $n$ distinct cats, how many ways can you choose a subset of all the animals to take for a walk?